# Not able to use array properly in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Context:
I am trying to use JSONSchema to run user-selected TestCases. Where a user can run the selected tests of a particular type.
Actual schema is big so I converted to small form here.

Problem:
I wanted to restrict the maximum user selections till 3. As I defined type is an array.

But on the screen user is able to add many tests. No restriction is showing for users.

Can anyone help here to restrict the user selection at 3 only at a time?

```
"TestRun": {
            "items": {

                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                                    "TestA": {
                                              "type": "boolean",
                                              },
                                    "TestB": {
                                             "type": "boolean",
                                             }
                                    }
                     },
              "prettyName": "Advanced Test ",
              "type": "array",
              "minItems": 0, 
              "maxItems": 3
            }
      }
```

Comment: Please provide a valid JSON Schema and instance examples you expect to pass and fail.

Comment: I am expecting user can select maximum 3 test type. Because on screen there are 100 of test cases. So that maxItems is set to 3.

Comment: Often what someone believes the problem is, and what the probably actually is, are not the same thing. I do not have enough information to help you. Please provide the required information if you would like help.